# What could be the root cause of this java.net.ConnectException, and how to resolve it?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jca

### The context

I'm trying to open an HTTP connection to a web site in a Java Enterprise application (deployed on a Wildfly 8.2 application server). I use a fairly standard tool to do this - the Jsoup library. *Most* of the time, the connection is opened without a problem, and I can read and parse the web site content (for further processing).

However, if once the open fails (times out) - it will never again succeed, **until the full restart** of the application. Any attempt to open a connection to the same website will fail with the same exception again. As if the application memorized the *inaccessible* status of the web site, and stuck to this hypothesis, without trying again. (I am fairly confident, that even when the web site is accessible, the application still throws this exception again and again.)

### The Exception

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449) [jsoup-1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434) [jsoup-1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181) [jsoup-1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170) [jsoup-1.8.1.jar:]
```

### The questions

- Can this be a Wildfly bug?
- Can this problem be solved inside the application server? For instance, tuning configuration parameters, setting up a HTTP connection pool (does such thing exist?)
- Is it correct at all to open an HTTP connection (that is: use a non-managed, non-transactional resource) in a Java Enterprise application?
- How else could I access something available only over HTTP? (besides opening a connection)
- Could developing a JCA adapter resolve this issue?
- Does such JCA adapter exist already? (I can't be the only one with this problem ...)

Comment: Would you please provide me with the code you have written? I think you release the thread after any exception thrown during execution time. The exact answer without monitoring the code is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that (in this specific case) the network was configured incorrectly. Not only JVM, several other programs experienced network issues.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting issue with dns cashing jdk does and has noting to do with wildfly itself.

Try setting networkaddress.cache.ttl or networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl system property to control how dns cache behaves.

For more details o. This see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html

Comment: Insightful comment. However the URL, my application fails to visit is specified by its IP address. Can the DNS caching still be blamed for such an exception?